# Can't get background location update on iOS 11

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ios11, xcode9, cllocation

I've added in .plist all 3 possible keys:

Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location Usage Description

My code is:

```
private lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    return manager
  }()

 @IBAction func enabledLocationUpdate(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
      locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
  }

extension LocationViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
      return
    }


    NSLog("New location is \(mostRecentLocation)")
}
```

When app in foreground I can see location updates, but when I pressed home button - location updates stopped.
What I'm doing wrong?

Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)
iOS 11.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be missing two things:

1. Set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `YES` on the `CLLocationManager` object.  See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates)
2. Enable "location" as a background mode in your Info.plist file.  See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25)